# Joining 4 tables using nested queries Oracle

Tags: oracle

I am using nested queries to achieve this:

Basically, I have this:

```
employee table:
employee_id, locale
audience table
employee_id
country table
country_name,country_code
country_language
country_code, geo
```

I need this:  employee_id,audience_id,country_name,locale from these tables that come under "APAC" geo:

I have this query:

```
SELECT employee_id 
FROM audience 
 WHERE employee_id IN 
      (SELECT employee_id  
       FROM employee
       WHERE LOCALE IN
                  (SELECT LOCALE 
                   FROM COUNTRY_LANGUAGE 
                    WHERE COUNTRY_CODE IN 
                          (SELECT COUNTRY_CODE 
                           FROM COUNTRY 
                           WHERE GEO='apac')
             )
     ) 
 ORDER BY employee_id);
```

This is throwing this error: "SQL command not properly ended"
Also, will this query produce right results if run properly? If not, can u suggest something else?

Used this as joins. Did not return anything:

```
select a.employee_id,
      a.locale,
      b.audience_id,
      c.LOCALE_CODE,
      d.COUNTRY_NAME
from employee a,
     audience b,
     country_language c,
     country d
where 
     a.employee_id=b.employee_ID 
     and d.geo='apac' 
     and d.country_code=c.country_code
     and a.locale=c.LOCALE_CODE;
```

Comment: You really should start using `JOIN`

Comment: You're opening three sets of parentheses, but closing 4; so just remove the final `)` before the semicolon. (We don't know the data or what results you expect; or if `'apac'` should be `'APAC'`. And why are you using nested queries instead of joins?)

Comment: Thanks. I need one other thing: I also need country_name and locale information from tables I have in nested queries. How to go about that?

Comment: Please suggest how to use join in this scenario.

Comment: and a.locale=c.LOCALE /* not locale_code */

Comment: `will this query produce right results if run properly` - it depends on what you think is the "right result". You did not describe what result you want to get, you only showed the SQL command which doesn't work, it's hard to guess by looking at  bad SQL what result you want to get. I vote to close this question as unclear.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use UNION SELECT